# Facing issue implementing Dbcontext in .net6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I'm facing issue with `DbContext` in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, getting exception connection dispose or closed. Because I'm using the same `DbContext` across the application, I face this issue when database related operation completed first time and I, trying to execute other operation to using `DbContext`, get an exception connection closed or dispose.

I know this is because of `DbContext` lifetime however I try to execute in second operation in separate thread with new `DbContext` by using `serviceProvider` but still same issue first operation executed and second one always failed.

Here's my manager code:

```
public class ClientServices : IClientServices
{
    private readonly Context _dbContext;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor; // Injected IHttpContextAccessor
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ApiClient _apiClient;
    private readonly LoggingService _logger;
    private readonly AzureFileShareService _azurefileshareservice;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ClientServices(Context dbContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IConfiguration configuration, AzureFileShareService azurefileshareservice, ApiClient apiClient,
        LoggingService logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _azurefileshareservice = azurefileshareservice;
        _apiClient = apiClient;// new ApiClient(_configuration);
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> GetReport(string tempNo, string tempype, Guid UserId)
    {
        byte[] report = null;

        var requestLogDto = new RptRequestLog();
        requestLogDto.UserId = UserId;
        requestLogDto.RequestTime = DateTime.Now;

        var obj = new
        {
            tempNo = tempNo,
            tempype = tempype
        };
        var customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            // some values...
                        };

        var response = await _apiClient.PostAsync(_configuration["client:URL"], obj, customHeaders);

        if (response.Data is byte[] byteArray)
        {
            report = byteArray;
        }

        var responseLogDto = new ResponseLog();
        responseLogDto.Doc = report;
        responseLogDto.ResponseTime = DateTime.Now;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var docUlr = await _uploadAzureFilestorage(params);
            responseLogDto.DocUrl = docUlr;

            loggingInSeparateThread(report, tempNo, requestLogDto, responseLogDto, "RptRequestLog", "RptResponseLog");
        });

        return report;
    }

    public async Task loggingInSeparateThread(byte[] report, string tempNo, dynamic requestLogDto, dynamic responseLogDto,
        string reqlogTable, string respLogtable)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();

            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                WriteIndented = true // Optional: for better readability
            };

            Log(requestLogDto, responseLogDto, reqlogTable, respLogtable, dbContext);

            AuditHistory(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestLogDto, options),
                               System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseLogDto, options),
                                requestLogDto.HshUserId, requestLogDto.RequestTime.Value, DateTime.Now, dbContext);
        }
    }

    public async Task Log(dynamic requestBody, dynamic responseBody, string requesTable, string responseTable, Context context)
    {
        var requestLogId = await _logger.LogToTable(requestBody, requesTable, context);
        responseBody.ReptRequestLogId = requestLogId;
        _logger.LogToTable(responseBody, responseTable, context);
    }

    public async Task AuditHistory(string requestBody, string responseBody, Guid UserId,
        DateTime requestTime, DateTime responseTime, Context context)
    {
        var auditHistory = new AuditHistory();
        auditHistory.RequestBody = requestBody;
        auditHistory.RequestTime = requestTime;
        auditHistory.ResponseBody = responseBody;
        auditHistory.ResponseTime = responseTime;

        await _logger.LogAuditHistory(auditHistory, "AuditHistory", context);
    }
}
```

Here's the logging service:

```
public class LoggingService
{
     private readonly Context context;

     public LoggingService(Context dbContext)
     {
         context = dbContext;
     }

     public async Task<Guid> LogToTable<T>(T model, string tableName,Context context) where T : class
     {
         try
         {
             var dbSet = context.Set<T>();
         
             dbSet.Add(model);
             await context.SaveChangesAsync();

             var idProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id");

             if (idProperty != null)
             {
                 var newId = (Guid)idProperty.GetValue(model);
                 return newId;
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }

         return Guid.Empty;
     }
}
```

Can anyone explain how to implement a generic solution to do this?

For reference consider this when log method call for inserting record in db the first operation executed(record inserted in db) successfully but when it goes to insert second time using:

```
_logger.LogToTable(responseBody, responseTable, context);
```

Then I get exception connection closed/dispose.

Comment: `* I'm using the same DbContext across the application*` ??

Comment: if i add interface for logging service and register it same as i register the clientservice or client interface it would work ??
is it correct way to do this ?

Comment: @PoulBak i meant i have single DB in my app.

Comment: Please [edit] your question's title so that it is more a summary of your specific issue than just a list of tags (after all, we have the tags box for that). See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: @HereticMonkey my bad, thanks for correcting me !

Answer (score 1):

This code here won't work:

```
public class LoggingService
{
     private readonly Context context;

     public LoggingService(Context dbContext)
     {
         context = dbContext;
     }

     public async Task<Guid> LogToTable<T>(T model, string tableName,Context context) where T : class
     {
         try
         {
             var dbSet = context.Set<T>();
         
             // ...
```

When performing operations within a background task, you cannot rely on an injected DbContext, it needs to be scoped within the task itself. The easiest way to get around this is to create a DbContextFactory and inject that into the class that has the background tasks' class instance, then the background task can use that to instantiate a scoped instance of the `DbContext`:

```
public class LoggingService
{
     private readonly IAppDbContextContextFactory contextFactory;

     public LoggingService(IAppDbContextFactory contextFactory)
     {
         this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
     }

     public async Task<Guid> LogToTable<T>(T model, string tableName,Context context) where T : class
     {
         try
         {
             using context = contextFactory.Create();

             var dbSet = context.Set<T>();
         
             dbSet.Add(model);
             await context.SaveChangesAsync();

             var idProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id");

             if (idProperty != null)
             {
                 var newId = (Guid)idProperty.GetValue(model);
                 return newId;
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }

         return Guid.Empty;
     }
}
```

That should solve the issue.  Things like controllers with `async` operations can use a `DbContext` scoped to the web request for example because those operations will be awaited and all executed within the span of the web request where the `DbContext` will be kept alive. If you hand off to a background worker and initialize it with that same `DbContext` instance you can run into various issues including the possibility that the background worker and web request try accessing the DbContext at the same time (cross thread issues as the DbContext is not thread safe) or situations where the web request ends, triggering the disposal of the DbContext and the background thread attempts to access a reference to it.

Edit: A DbContextFactory isn't anything particularly complex, just a class that can serve a new instance of a `DbContext` on request. The implementation can be tied into whatever dependency injection you use, or a crude `return new AppDbContext(configuration)` within a class.

An implementation that I use with Autofac:

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    TDbContext CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : DbContext;
}


/// <summary>
/// Factory class for DbContextScopes to facilitate the 
/// AmbientDbContextScopeFactory while allowing our DbContext's to 
/// track modified state.
/// </summary>
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _containerLifetimeScope;

    public DbContextFactory(ILifetimeScope containerLifetimeScope)
    {
        _containerLifetimeScope = containerLifetimeScope ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(containerLifetimeScope));
    }

    TDbContext IDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext<TDbContext>()
    {
        return _containerLifetimeScope.Resolve<TDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Autofac injects itself as the lifetime scope, and when you call CreateDbContext this asks Autofac for a new instance.

You could do something as crude as:

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    AppDbContext CreateDbContext();
}


[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    AppDbContext IDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new AppDbContext("YourConnectionString");
    }
}
```

... and that would get the job done.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i face another issue if i call any method which is inside clientservice also facing the same issue could you please guide how to avoid these types of issue ?

Comment: for example i have a method to sendemail in client service which i call in separate thread using Task.Run(()=> await sendmail()) in this method i have to check some values from db its executed successfully but after sending email i need to update db so here i get again same exception.

Comment: Make sure every call is awaited.  For instance in your code I see calls to _logger.LogToTable that are awaited, and other calls that are not. This is a bit of a "trap" with relying on asynchronous code especially calls where results are somewhat optional. It's easy to accidentally kick one or more off and forget the `await` especially when you ignore the response. At least when getting the response you might spot the issue where you expect a string or object and intellisense shows you are given a `Task<T>` back. Hunt down any `async ` calls not awaited, and any `Task` methods not `async`.

Comment: Yes, any and every background process you start with `Task.Run` must use the same structure with a DbCotextFactory and scoping a `DbContext` within the executing method. if these are run in parallel or "abandoned" to execute (or not successfully) in the background.

Comment: could you please show me some example to implement DbContextFactory or share some simple resource for me, Thanks alot

Comment: I added the DbContextFactory implementation that I use /w Autofac. Something similar should be easy enough to implement with other containers. I also put in a bare-bones example.